# Only one monitor shows options in nvidia-settings

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitors setup with Ubuntu 11.04.  One is a dell and other is HannsG.  I suspect that the HannsG monitor is not setup correctly as the colors look very weird.

I think the problem is with `nvidia-settings` not showing all options for my HannsG monitor.

Dell Monitor Settings:
[image]

HannsG Monitor Settings
[image]

This is the relevant section of my `xorg.conf`

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
EndSubSection
```

**Question**
What do I need to do in order to see all the settings for my HannsG monitor?

Answer (score 5):

Its a known xorg bug with your HannsG monitor. There is no solution for it at the moment, maybe you can push the bug to active since the last post about it was in 2010. Its the same issue.

The launchpad link for your problem is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-nv/+bug/474816